# replacing a character in 2d array

Tags: c++

EDIT***

I am having trouble replacing a character in the 2-d array. Initially, my code reads from the text file and stores the data in the temporary string. I am confused about how I can replace the characters with a different one. I used nested for loops but the code doesn't work. Thanks for help!

I'm trying to replace p with '*' and w with '~'

```
string temp;      
string arr3[25][16];
arr1[16];
int i =0;
int j =0; 
ifstream inputfiles; 

inputfiles.open("mapPoke.txt"); 

if (inputfiles.is_open())
{
    while (getline(inputfiles, temp))
    {
        split(temp, ',', arr1, 16);
        arr3[i][j] = temp;
        for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++)
            {
                if (temp[j] == 'p'){
                    temp[j] = '*';   
                } 
                else if (temp[j] == 'w')
                {
                    temp[j] = '~';
                }
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

This is the data that I'm trying to replace

```
w,w,w,w,w,w,w,p,p,p,p,p,p,p,p,p
p,w,w,w,w,w,w,G,p,p,C,p,p,p,G,p
p,w,w,w,w,w,w,p,p,p,p,p,p,p,p,p
p,w,G,w,w,w,w,p,p,p,p,p,p,p,p,p
p,p,p,p,w,w,w,p,p,p,p,G,p,p,p,p
p,C,w,w,w,w,w,p,C,p,p,p,p,C,p,p
p,p,p,w,w,w,w,w,p,p,p,p,p,p,p,p
p,p,p,p,w,w,w,p,p,p,p,p,p,p,p,G
p,G,p,p,w,w,p,p,p,p,p,p,p,p,p,p
p,p,p,w,w,p,p,C,p,p,p,C,p,p,C,p
p,p,p,w,w,p,p,w,G,p,p,p,p,p,p,p
p,w,p,C,w,w,p,w,w,w,p,G,w,w,p,p
p,w,p,p,p,w,p,p,p,p,p,p,w,w,w,G
p,C,G,w,w,w,p,p,p,C,p,w,w,w,w,w
p,p,w,w,w,w,w,p,p,p,p,w,w,w,w,w
p,p,w,w,w,w,w,p,p,p,p,w,w,w,w,w
p,p,p,w,w,w,w,w,w,p,p,p,w,w,w,w
p,G,p,w,w,w,w,w,w,C,p,p,w,w,w,w
p,p,w,w,w,w,w,w,p,p,p,w,w,w,w,w
p,p,w,w,w,w,w,w,G,p,C,w,w,w,w,w
p,p,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,p,p,p,w,w,w,w
p,p,C,w,w,w,w,w,w,p,p,p,G,w,w,w
p,p,p,p,p,p,G,p,p,p,p,p,p,w,p,w
p,G,p,p,p,p,p,C,p,p,p,p,C,p,p,w
p,p,p,p,p,p,p,p,p,p,p,p,p,p,p,p
```

It has 25 rows and 16 columns.

I'm also confused on how I should cout the array after replacing the values. Thanks for the help and sorry for any mistakes as I'm quite new to C++.

Comment: Please reformat the code, and additionally include at least the declarations/definitions of temp, arr1, arr3 etc.

Comment: It looks like `temp[j]` should be `temp[i, j]`, as you're only referring to one of your indices. Also, what do you mean by "The code doesn't work"? What errors are you getting?

Comment: So, just to be clear, your goal is to read the mapPoke.txt file, convert every 'p' to '*' and every 'w' to '~' and then print the modified lines of text to stdout?

Comment: Yes. Read and then print the replaced version of the p and w

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use [string replace](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/replace/) to make your life easier!

EDIT: I tested this below and it works for your example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   char arr[25][16];
   int i=0; int j=0;
   string temp; char c;

   ifstream fin("mapPoke.txt");
   if(!fin){ cerr << "Couldn't open file\n"; }

   while(getline(fin,temp)){
      if(!temp.empty()){
         //find and replace p's
         while(temp.find('p') != string::npos){
            temp.replace(temp.find('p'),1,1,'*');
         }
         //find and replace w's
         while(temp.find('w') != string::npos){
            temp.replace(temp.find('w'),1,1,'~');
         }
         //erase commas 
         while(temp.find(',') != string::npos){
            temp.erase(temp.find(','),1);
         }
         //here all w's and p's have been replaced, and commas are removed
         //uncomment the line below if you want to see the output
            //cout << temp << endl;

         //insert in array, character by character
         for(int k=0;k<temp.length();k++){
            arr[i][j++]=temp[k];
         }
         j=0;
         i++;
      }
   }
   fin.close();


   //and to cout the 2D array 
   for(i=0;i<25;i++){
      for(j=0;j<16;j++){
         cout<< arr[i][j];
      }
      cout<<endl;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

And the output is this:

```
~~~~~~~*********
*~~~~~~G**C***G*
*~~~~~~*********
*~G~~~~*********
****~~~****G****
*C~~~~~*C****C**
***~~~~~********
****~~~********G
*G**~~**********
***~~**C***C**C*
***~~**~G*******
*~*C~~*~~~*G~~**
*~***~******~~~G
*CG~~~***C*~~~~~
**~~~~~****~~~~~
**~~~~~****~~~~~
***~~~~~~***~~~~
*G*~~~~~~C**~~~~
**~~~~~~***~~~~~
**~~~~~~G*C~~~~~
**~~~~~~~***~~~~
**C~~~~~~***G~~~
******G******~*~
*G*****C****C**~
****************
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to use string replace on 2d array? Is there a another way?

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you're trying to do. Can you show the rest of your code?

Comment: Thanks for updating your question, I've updated my answer with the code. Let me know if you have any questions. Cheers!

Comment: Just a quick question though, what does npos mean and what does it do?

Comment: It's an extremely large number. If find() returns "string::npos" it means that the value was not found in the string. Otherwise, it will return the position where it is found in the string.

Check it out [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/npos/)

Comment: Sorry for this late question, if I now had to change the character from the replaced version on a specific row and column, how would I go about it?

Comment: If you want to replace the 3rd character on the 4th row, which is a ‘G’, with the character ‘X’. You use 2D array notation where you specify the outer array first (ie:the row) and then the inner array (ie: the column), as such:   arr[3][2] = ‘X’;

Comment: Does that answer your question?